# how to create a sub-element through variable in python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, elementtree, xml.etree

My code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree
var1 = '<name>This is my text</name>'
page = etree.Element('first')
doc = etree.ElementTree(page)
second = etree.SubElement(page, 'second')
second.text = var1
doc.write('a.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

My output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<first><second>&lt;name&gt;This is my text&lt;/name&gt;</second></first>
```

My Desired Output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<first><second><name>This is my text</name></second></first>
```

Actually, I want to create sub-element through variable and I don't know how many elements are available in our variable. this is only for test purpose so please take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create a subelement by supplying it as a string of XML markup. The `<name>` element has to be created using `SubElement`, just like `<second>`.

The following code produces the desired output:

```
from lxml import etree

page = etree.Element('first')
second = etree.SubElement(page, 'second')
name = etree.SubElement(second, 'name')
name.text = "This is my text"

doc = etree.ElementTree(page)
doc.write('a.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

An alternative is to parse the `<name>This is my text</name>` string into an `Element` object and append it to the parent:

```
from lxml import etree

var1 = '<name>This is my text</name>'
name = etree.fromstring(var1)

page = etree.Element('first')
second = etree.SubElement(page, 'second')
second.append(name)

doc = etree.ElementTree(page)
doc.write('b.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```